# Multiplayer turn-based game with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, multiplayer

I want to build a multiplayer, turn-based web app/game with Rails. There will be a room where a limited amount of users can join and take turns. Users can enter the room without invitation (if it's public), or with invitations (if it's private). Users can view a room without participating, as well. Also, players can change at any time during the game, so the game would adjust accordingly. The room should be open as long the creator allows it to be, since the game has no set duration. I'm fairly new at Rails and would like to know if it's possible to make a game like this.

I have some controllers and models set up already, but don't want to continue if it's not possible or recommended to use Rails.

### Some additional info.

As per usual, the following steps will repeat themselves.

- Player makes move
- Move is registered and saved to the db
- The screen is updated with the player's move.
- Turn goes to next available player.

The info saved to the db will be small (few KBs) and shouldn't take too long to show up in the screen. During a turn, only one person can do anything. The rest are just viewing the screen, it'll be one update at a time per room.

If the player whose turn it is does not respond for x seconds, either the player is made a guest, or his/her turn is skipped until the next round (to be determined yet).

I did some research and found out that Google Play Games offers a turn-based multiplayer service that's supported through the REST API. I'm not entirely sure that it would work, but I would appreciate suggestions to other services that may be suitable for implementing turn-base multiplayer functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a web application then you can use Rails as well as any other web programming language with its corresponding application framework. However my experience tells me that you **should not use Rails if you're going to put the game on a generic hosting provider**. Most of them are more PHP-friendly and do not provide support for running Rails apps. However, you can do it in [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) for free with certain limitations. If you need more resources, then you should pay monthly for them.

Comment: Yeah, it's a web application. I have been deploying to Heroku for testing, so it's good to know it's an option. Thanks for letting me know about the generic hosts.